# how to stop duplication in firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to authentication in my chat app so when user signedin one time so the data will insert on firbase database but when user just refresh his chrome so one another same  data will added again so i want to stop duplication if user already inserted so i tried this code mentioned below but this is not working.

```
function onStateChanged(user) {
    if (user) {
        //alert(firebase.auth().currentUser.email + '\n' + firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName);

        var userProfile = { email: '', name: '', photoURL: '' };
        userProfile.email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
        userProfile.name = firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName;
        userProfile.photoURL = firebase.auth().currentUser.photoURL;

        var db = firebase.database().ref('users');
        var flag = false;
        db.on('value', function (users) {
            users.forEach(function (data) {
                var user = data.val();
                if (user.email === userProfile.email) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            });

            if (flag === false) {
                firebase.database().ref('users').push(userProfile, callback);
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('imgProfile').src = firebase.auth().currentUser.photoURL;
                console.log('elsepart')
                document.getElementById('imgProfile').title = firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName;

                document.getElementById('lnkSignIn').style = 'display:none';
                document.getElementById('lnkSignOut').style = '';
            }
        });
        
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('imgProfile').src = image/profile-image.png;
        document.getElementById('imgProfile').title = '';

        document.getElementById('linkSignIn').style = '';
        document.getElementById('linkSignOut').style = 'display: none';
    }
}

let callback = (error)=>{
    if(error){
        alert(error)
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('imgProfile').src = firebase.auth().currentUser.photoURL;
        document.getElementById('imgProfile').title = firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName;

        document.getElementById('linkSignIn').style = 'display: none';
        document.getElementById('linkSignOut').style = '';
    }
}

///////////

onFirebaseStateChanged();
```

Comment: Why do you want to store user information again in a separate table. You might want to call admin.auth().listUsers on the server side and create an api to access it client side.

Comment: actually I am creating Chat app with google authentication so when user sign in once so i get the data like name email photoURL and stored in the database but when user again refresh page so the same data will again stored with another table.

Answer (score 0):

you can try firebase read and write functions to do this, for reference: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

I have done something kind of similar. Here, I have checked my db for same entries, if that doesn't exist, only then it'll allow you to register.

```
firebase.database().ref('/login/' + username).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.val() === null || snapshot.val() === undefined) {
           firebase.database().ref('login/' + username).set({
               name: name,
               email: username,
               password: password
           });
           _this.setState({
               showAlert: true,
               alertMessage: "User has been successfully register. Please login",
               alertType: 'success'
           })
       } else {
           console.log("in true")
           _this.setState({
               showAlert: true,
               alertMessage: "User already exist",
               alertType: 'warning'
           })
       }
```

Also, for remaining in the same logged in state even after refresh, creating session storage seems like an easy solution to me.